# How to check value in inner class?

Tags: java, runnable, final

I want to check whether a value retains its value and take a particular action onChange. I have to constantly check whether the value has changed, so I need it to be a new `Runnable` on a separate `Thread`.(If this is not the case, please let me know) But I cannot check for the value inside a sub class(inner class) because I will need to declare the value as `final`.But the whole point is to not let the variable be `final`. The datatype is int

```
while (true) {

                    //check whether value has changed
                }
```

Using

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(valueHasChanged()){//valueHasChanged will require the variable to be final
                    yes();
            }
        }).start();
```

*The above code has been cleaned to remove unecessaty stuff.*

Comment: Some related code will help understand the problem.

Comment: If you have control over when the value changes (i.e. just in the `setValue()` method) then you can fire the listeners from there.

Comment: What is the data type of the variable

Comment: @gargkshitiz it is an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use a queuing model with a limited number of items, say 1024. This is because the rate of value change might be different than the rate of execution of the `yes()` method. Queuing model is simpler and can be extended/tweaked in future if required.

Code will look like this, I have omitted the `InterruptedException` catch block for readability:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Boolean> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1024);

while (true) {
    .....
    //check whether value has changed and do
    queue.put(true);
    .....
}

....
....

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(queue.take()){
           yes();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: How can you `put` to a final Queue

Comment: Try it once! queue's reference is final, but you should be able to do put and take

Comment: will try it, thanks. Didnt know that final variable could be altered

Comment: Use the latest code, made a small edit. Please upvote and accept it as an answer if it helps

Comment: it worked, could u explain why a final variable can be altered

Comment: 'final non-primitive variable' cannot be changed to refer to any other object and that's about it. The members of the referred object can still be changed

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty`. Run this simple test to see how :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimpleIntegerProperty monitorValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    monitorValue.set(4);
    monitorValue.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue ) ->{
        System.out.println(oldValue+ " changed to "+ newValue);
    });
    monitorValue.set(5);
}
```

Output

> 4 changed to 5